# get end date and start date in full calender

Tags: jquery

```
eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
     console.log(event.title)
     var EventId=event.eventId;
},
```

hhw to get event start date and end date in eventDragStop function in full calenderplugin when event is dragged to another date?

Comment: Not sure but did you try `event.start` and `event.end` ? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Start Date

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start._d
```

End Date

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end._d
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/34md6Lw6/)